# Backbone.js - multiple models for one view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a template that needs to receive data from two different API endpoints (URLs): `cart` and `user`.

I want the two endpoints to act as one model or collection so that I can do something like `.changedAttributes()` or `sync`, or `fetch`.

I know Backbone is very permissive, but I am really lost.

---

### Playground:

I've created a codepen to see what I've done so far: http://codepen.io/anything/pen/AXoBoa

---

Desired result should be something like:

```
initialize: function(){
  var self = this;
  collection.fetch({
  success: function(data){
      self.collection = data;
    }
  })
},

render: function(){
    var self = this;
    var source = $("#template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var htmlToRender = template(self.collection.toJSON());
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need the two endpoints to act as 1 model? It might make it simpler to create a model for each and listen to the 'sync' event on each individually and render parts of the view that correspond to each because cart and user are logically two separate entities.

Comment: @noahpc true, but if a user is doing logout, the cart view will not know about it and it will still show x items in cart even if the current user has nothing in the cart on db....Anyways, I understand what you are saying, will see in the future how things play out.

Comment: Makes sense. I added another answer which takes a slightly different approach. Let me know if you have any questions about exactly how to implement it in your case.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an event concentrator listening to its registered objects and retrigger the events you catch.

Something like

```
var aggregate = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
aggregate.register = function(m) {
    var self = this;

    this.listenTo(m, 'all', function() {
        this.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
    });
};
```

You would then use it like this

```
aggregate.on('change', function(m) {
    // do what you have to do when one of the models change
    console.log('Change on ', m.toJSON());
});
aggregate.on('sync', function(m) {
    //same thing for syncs
    console.log('sync ', m.toJSON());
});

var m1 = new Backbone.Model({id: 1});
var m2 = new Backbone.Model({id: 2});
aggregate.register(m1);
aggregate.register(m2);

m1.fetch();
m2.set({data: 2});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/hm0xc79z/

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach to nikoshr based on http://backbonejs.org/#Events. The basic idea is that you set up an event object that can be referenced in both views. You can name the events whatever you want and they can triggered and listened to wherever the object is available.

1. Create event object. In your case, add it to your main appshell object.

   ```
   appShell.Events = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
   ```
2. When user performs action in user view like logout, trigger an event.

   ```
   appShell.Events.trigger('user:logout');
   ```
3. Listen to the event in another view and perform action based off of it.

   ```
   this.listenTo(appShell.Events, 'user:logout', this.doSomething);
   ```
4. Put logic in the doSomething to do whatever you need to do on the other view.